# Bootstrap collapse data-parent not working

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 2.2.1 and for whatever reason the data-parent attribute is not doing what is intended. It does not close a previous opened target when i click another target. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b9UuC/6/) with the code below, any ideas on how to fix this ?

```
<div id="accordion">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#document', data-parent='#accordion'>option 1</a>
            <ul id="document" class="collapse">
                <li> <a href="#">suboption 1</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#">suboption 1</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#">suboption 1</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">option 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">option 3</a>
        </li>
         <li>
            <a href="#" data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#document2', data-parent='#accordion'>option 4</a>
            <ul id="document2" class="collapse">
                <li> <a href="#">suboption 1</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#">suboption 1</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#">suboption 1</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I couldn't get this to work either - this may be something in the Bootstrap JS related to the fact that you are using lists rather than divs?

So to get it to work, I had to override the click event. Based on this question here: [Collapsible accordion doesn't work inside a dropdpwn-menu Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182215/collapsible-accordion-doesnt-work-inside-a-dropdpwn-menu-bootstrap)

I added an `accordion-toggle` class to each option link, and then added the following JavaScript to get it to work:

```
$(document).on('click', '.accordion-toggle', function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        var $this = $(this);

        var parent = $this.data('parent');
        var actives = parent && $(parent).find('.collapse.in');

        // From bootstrap itself
        if (actives && actives.length) {
            hasData = actives.data('collapse');
            //if (hasData && hasData.transitioning) return;
            actives.collapse('hide');
        }

        var target = $this.attr('data-target') || (href = $this.attr('href')) && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, ''); //strip for ie7

        $(target).collapse('toggle');
});​
```

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/YZMEL/2/) shows it in action.

Comment: I used your code in my project and it is not working with IE9/8

Answer (score 9):

It says in the Bootstrap Documents:

> If a selector is provided, then all collapsible elements under the
>   specified parent will be closed when this collapsible item is shown.
>   (similar to traditional accordion behavior - *this is dependent on the
>   `panel` class*)

so it has to be used with panel-groups, but you can override the javascript anyway.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-options

Comment: I can't speak for what the case was in 2012, but this is the correct answer from what I'm seeing today. I stepped through Bootstrap's collapse.js to discover it was dependent on the targets being (directly) under the panel class within the same parent. Felt pretty smart about that, then saw you said exactly that and pointed out where it was in the documentation.

Comment: I would add - `data-parent` is supposed to be used *instead* of `data-target`, not alongside.

Comment: Bootstrap 4 is the same, except it is the .card class instead of .panel.

Answer (score 7):

've been struggling with bootstrap collapse as well.  I was trying to something do something slightly different.  I wanted inline toggle behavior. See my JS fiddle below.  What I found is that bootstrap seems to require the existence of the "accordion-group" div in addition to the data-parent attribute covered in their docs.  So either there is a bug in the JS or their docs do not include it. I also had to zero out the styles on the accordion-group div...

http://jsfiddle.net/cssguru/SRFFJ/

```
<div id="accordion2">
   <div class="accordion-group" style="border:0;padding:0;margin:0">
      <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse in">
            Foo Bar...
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
               Show Herp Derp
            </a>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse">
            Herp Derp...
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
               Show Foo Bar
            </a> 
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: jsfiddle is no more valid

Answer (score 5):

You have to use accordion-group class in your items, see issue https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/4988