# How to expand only one li on click?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So what im trying to do is when user click on one of items to expand it.  But that expand only that li, to show data bellow it. 
This is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LLkaj4h0/ Any suggestion?

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="row">
                <ul class="list-of-consalting">
                    <li>    
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" style="background-color:transparent;border:none;" data-target="#finansijskimenadjment">
                        <span>Finansijski menadžment</span><span style="color:#c20c0c;margin-left:5px;" class="fa fa-angle-down"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div id="finansijskimenadjment" class="collapse ">
                            <ul class="expand-details">
                            <li>posebni konsalting po zahtjevima manje složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
                            <li>posebni konsalting projekti po zahtevima veće složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                    <li>    
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" style="background-color:transparent;border:none;" data-target="#racunovodstvenosavjetovanje">
                        <span>Računovodstveno savjetovanje</span><span style="color:#c20c0c;margin-left:5px;" class="fa fa-angle-down"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div id="racunovodstvenosavjetovanje" class="collapse ">
                            <ul class="expand-details">
                            <li>posebni konsalting po zahtjevima manje složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
                            <li>posebni konsalting projekti po zahtevima veće složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                    <li>    
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" style="background-color:transparent;border:none;" data-target="#poreznosavjetovanje">
                        <span>Porezno savjetovanje</span><span style="color:#c20c0c;margin-left:5px;" class="fa fa-angle-down"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div id="poreznosavjetovanje" class="collapse ">
                            <ul class="expand-details">
                            <li>posebni konsalting po zahtjevima manje složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
                            <li>posebni konsalting projekti po zahtevima veće složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                    <li>    
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" style="background-color:transparent;border:none;" data-target="#javnefinansije">
                        <span>Javne finansije - budžet i trezor</span><span style="color:#c20c0c;margin-left:5px;" class="fa fa-angle-down"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div id="javnefinansije" class="collapse">
                            <ul class="expand-details">
                            <li>posebni konsalting po zahtjevima manje složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
                            <li>posebni konsalting projekti po zahtevima veće složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                    <li>    
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" style="background-color:transparent;border:none;" data-target="#korporativnoposlovnopravo">
                        <span>Korporativno - poslovno pravo</span><span style="color:#c20c0c;margin-left:5px;" class="fa fa-angle-down"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div id="korporativnoposlovnopravo" class="collapse">
                            <ul class="expand-details">
                            <li>posebni konsalting po zahtjevima manje složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
                            <li>posebni konsalting projekti po zahtevima veće složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                    <li>    
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" style="background-color:transparent;border:none;" data-target="#eufondovi">
                        <span>EU fondovi</span><span style="color:#c20c0c;margin-left:5px;" class="fa fa-angle-down"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div id="#eufondovi" class="collapse">
                            <ul class="expand-details">
                            <li>posebni konsalting po zahtjevima manje složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
                            <li>posebni konsalting projekti po zahtevima veće složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                    <li>    
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" style="background-color:transparent;border:none;" data-target="#usaglasavanjezakonodavstva">
                        <span>Usaglašavanje zakonodavstva sa pravom Evropske unije</span><span style="color:#c20c0c;margin-left:5px;" class="fa fa-angle-down"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div id="usaglasavanjezakonodavstva" class="collapse">
                            <ul class="expand-details">
                            <li>posebni konsalting po zahtjevima manje složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
                            <li>posebni konsalting projekti po zahtevima veće složenosti, po ugovoru</li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `jquery.min.js` before `bootstrap.min.js`. bootstrap has build in this functionality.

Spacing issue is because of `float:left` property in `ul.list-of-consalting li` selector. I have updated `width` property in this selector & also added `float:right` property to `li:nth-child(even)` selector.

**Updated CSS:**

```
ul.list-of-consalting > li {
    list-style: decimal;
    font-family: 'PT_Sans_Caption_Bold';
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #282828;
    float: left;
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
    list-style-position: inside;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

ul.list-of-consalting > li:nth-child(even){
    float: right;
}
```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/LLkaj4h0/6/)

css updated line no `[1371-1386]` in jsfiddle link.

Comment: i know..tnx...but my problem is when i click on right menu it add height also on left side and i want to avoid that...any suggestion?

Comment: @None i have updated my answer, please check. Hope this will work for you.

Comment: thats it ...tnx a lot :)

Comment: just one more question...what i need to do to expand only one li on click? i tried to use data-parent but it not works

Comment: @None Yes, i also know the use of `data-parent` attribute to achieve this. Here's the post about similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665800/bootstrap-collapse-data-parent-not-working

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a click event to all of yours button for update the classe of the next div

```
$(".dropdown-toggle").on('click', function(){
    $(this).find('+ div').toggleClass('collapse');
  })
```

It's a best solution to not select all next `div` but next classes like this

```
$(this).find('+ .collapse-container').toggleClass('collapse');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/LLkaj4h0/2/

Comment: @kevpccs when i open menu od right side it add me height on menu on left side... is it possible to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function() {
    $($(this).data('target')).toggleClass('collapse');
});
```

Check this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/LLkaj4h0/3/)

Attach a click event handler on `.dropdown-toggle` button and get the target panel's `id` from `data-target` attribute and then find this target element and toggle its `collapse` class to show and hide the panel.

Comment: when i expand menu on right side it expand me also menu on left side...it add height...is it possible to avoid that